# Why won't partial refresh work

Tags: javascript, xpages

Trying another XPages nested partial refresh on multiple items.  The refresh is to happen when the combo list box named conTenderType value changes with the onChange event and refreshes the panels ContractWorkflowPanel and ContractDetailPanel.  All the panels are in a djTabContainer.  There is no requirement for rendering conditions on the target panel components.  I have tried the script shown below in the Client javascript for conTenderType onChange event but it doesn't work.  I have also tried changing onComplete to onStart etc.  Why won't this work?

```
XSP.partialRefreshPost("#{id:conTenderType}", {
  onComplete: function() {
  XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:ContractWorkflowPanel}", {
      onComplete: function() { XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:ContractDetailPanel}"); }
  }) 
}
})
```

Thanks

Comment: What version of Notes/Domino are you using and which browsers have you tested in?

Comment: Test the code in Firefox and activate Developer panel and see if you have any javascript errors

Comment: @MichaelG.Smith - Domino release is 8.5.3 and browser is I.E 8

Comment: As Frederik suggested, test in FF or Chrome.  I'm pretty sure I've had issues with earlier versions of IE and onChange.

Comment: @FredrikNorling - I have opened it in FireFox and opened what I think is the developer panel using "Shift" + F2 and it opens a small thin console at bottom browser.  Im afraid I am not sure what to do now.  The console has a JS button which I ensured was selected and I changed the Combo Box value and it did place an entry in the Javascript panel but nothing that I can use to help me!!

Comment: Press CTRL+Shift+K then the developer console will show up then reload the page and Press on the button that should to the partial refresh. If you get any errors that might be your problem, try to fix the errors, if they come from your code.

Comment: @FredrikNorling - Thanks.  I will have a go and using this to inspect the Javascript but as stated in my communication with Paul Stephen Withers below it may be that the refresh process and the validation in the Workflow tab do not mix well and users may just have to put up with using Save button to refresh the Workflow tab.  Thank again

Answer (score 0):

Are there any validated fields? Unless "Process data without validation" is ticked, validation will occur. (The other way to prevent validation occurring is ticking "Do not validate or update data", but then you will not be updating the server-side component tree with the value the user has selected for the combo box, so there's no point setting that.)

If no execId is set, all controls on the page are validated. If validation fails, the only update sent back to the browser will be error messages for the validation failures.

I would always advise ensuring your refresh area includes an Error Messages control, so you know if validation has failed. If you don't need to validate, tick "Process data without validation". If you do, and you don't want to refresh an area including an Error Messages control, you'll need to set execId, but you'll need to read about and understand what that does, to ensure values entered by the user are updated as required and not overwritten by the response to the browser.

Comment: Thanks Paul Stephen Withers.  This might be the problem.  I know the ContractDetailPanel is refreshing because after the change to the conTenderType combo box value the combo box highlighting goes off almost immediately.  However, the ContractWorkflowPanel contains many fields and it is set up as a workflow with contract work stages and so I know there is validation working there and the validation is necessary.  I am thinking now that the users may just have to live with using the "Save" button to refresh things.